# Adding the filename to the first row of a file in linux

Tags: linux, cat

I got a lot of file like this

```
 1   rs10488368     180568    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05    
 1    rs2906334     189547    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05   
 2   rs10092114     190451    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05    
 3    rs2906347     198834    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05
```

named like this plinky.P1.assoc.linear, plinky.P2.assoc.linear etc...

I combined them all using `cat *.assoc.linear > all_files.tx`t but then in the end I don't know which line came from which file...

So what I hope to get is a file with all the files (plinky.P1.assoc.linear, plinky.P2.assoc.linear etc...) like this:

```
   1   rs10488368     180568    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05  plinky.P1.assoc.linear    
   1    rs2906334     189547    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05  plinky.P1.assoc.linear       
   1   rs10092114     190451    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    2.253e-04  plinky.P1.assoc.linear    
   1    rs2906347     198834    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05  plinky.P1.assoc.linear    
   1   rs10488368     180568    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    4.513e-05  plinky.P2.assoc.linear    
   1    rs2906334     189547    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.913e-05  plinky.P2.assoc.linear    
   2   rs11988064     190422    C        ADD       11     -1.292       -1.329       0.2165  plinky.P2.assoc.linear    
   2   rs10092114     190451    T        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05  plinky.P3.assoc.linear    
   3    rs2906347     198834    C        ADD       11     -2.714       -7.016    6.213e-05  plinky.P3.assoc.linear    
   4   rs11782267     201877    C        ADD       11     -1.292       -1.329       0.2165  plinky.P3.assoc.linear    
   8    rs3008268     202123    T        ADD       11       -1.9        -1.25       0.2428  plinky.P3.assoc.linear    
   8   rs10435671     202498    T        ADD       11       -1.9        -1.25       0.2428  plinky.P3.assoc.linea
```

r

etc...

But it looks to me very difficult to make, so don't know if this is feasible...

Thanks for any help!

Floris

Comment: Your title does not match your problem description - please fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solution combines `cat` with `sed` for the desired output

```
for f in *.txt ; do cat $f | sed 's/$/ '$f'/'  >> all_files.txt; done
```